# Pandas: Unhashable type list

Tags: pandas

I'm using this code to drop values with condition
`df['CNT_CHILDREN'] =df.drop([df['CNT_CHILDREN'] > 10].index)`

As an error i have this result

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: do you want to drop values from column 'CNT_CHILDREN' which are greater than 10?

Comment: @TalhaTayyab yes

Comment: Drop values or drop rows?

Comment: @Corralien drop rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['CNT_CHILDREN'] > 10].index)
#            ^--- you forgot df
```

`df.drop` method drop specified labels from rows so you have to pass the index and not the rows themselves.

```
>>> df[df['CNT_CHILDREN'] > 10].index
Int64Index([3, 5, 8, 13], dtype='int64')  # dummy data
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, could you please explain .index  in the end ? For what it ? Ik that it is also in my own code but cannot get it ;C @Corralien